# PHP MySQLi - Variables not handed over from session

Tags: php, session, mysqli

I am having troubles with my session variables being taken over to all relevant member pages. What I would like to do is to first match the input for username and password against the database and once an accurate member account has been found, pull all member table information for that particular member. After all the table data has been pulled, each column should be assigned to a variable before being stored in the session for further use on the website.

This works well for $myusername and $mypassword, but it doesnt seem to work for any other variables. On the other website I am merely echoing the assigned $variable and the value should pop up.

```
<?php

session_start();

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

// include database access information
include '../MySQL/connect_db.php';
$tbl_name = 'GPA_properties';

 // Connect to server and select databse.
$mysqli=new MySQLi("$dbhost", "$dbuser", "$dbpass", "$dbname");
if($mysqli->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
    }

// Define $myusername and $mypassword as well as escape & stripslashes to protect against MySQL injection
$myusername = stripslashes(mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['myusername']));
$mypassword = stripslashes(mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['mypassword']));

// Define query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' AND password='$mypassword'";
    if(!$result = $mysqli->query($sql)){
        die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
    }

// count how many rows are returned
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)==1) {
    // Register $myusername, $mypassword
         $_SESSION['myusername']=$myusername;
         $_SESSION['mypassword']=$mypassword;

    // register all other data as blank first
        $activation_date = "";
        $status = "";
        $holidex = "";
        $gpa_email = "";
        $gm = "";
        $gm_email = "";
        $phone_cc = "";
        $phone = "";
        $property = "";
        $address1 = "";
        $address2 = "";
        $zip = "";
        $city = "";
        $country = "";

        // grab all other information based on username
        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT Activation_Date, status, Holidex, Property_Name, GPA_Distribution_Email, General_Manager, GM_Email, Address_1, Address_2, ZIP, City, State, Country, Phone_CC, Phone FROM $tbl_name WHERE username=?")) {
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $myusername);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($activation_date, $status, $holidex, $property, $gpa_email, $gm, $gm_email, $address1, $address2, $zip, $city, $state, $country, $phone_cc, $phone);
            $stmt->fetch();
            }

        // define variables with acquired information
            $_SESSION['Activation_Date']=$activation_date;
            $_SESSION['status']=$status;
            $_SESSION['Holidex']=$holidex;
            $_SESSION['Property_Name']=$property;
            $_SESSION['GPA_Distribution_Email']=$gpa_email;
            $_SESSION['General_Manager']=$gm;
            $_SESSION['GM_Email']=$gm_email;
            $_SESSION['Address_1']=$address1;
            $_SESSION['Address_2']=$address2;
            $_SESSION['ZIP']=$zip;
            $_SESSION['City']=$city;
            $_SESSION['State']=$state;
            $_SESSION['Country']=$country;
            $_SESSION['Phone_CC']=$phone_cc;
            $_SESSION['Phone']=$phone;

            $stmt->close();

    // redirect to login_success.php
        header("location:login_success.php");
        exit;

    } else {
        echo "Wrong Username or Password";
    }

$mysqli->close();

?>
```

Anyone mind to have a look?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`status` is a reserved keyword in MySQL.

Try this in stead for the second query:

```
"SELECT Activation_Date, `status`, Holidex, Property_Name, GPA_Distribution_Email, General_Manager, GM_Email, Address_1, Address_2, ZIP, City, State, Country, Phone_CC, Phone FROM $tbl_name WHERE username=?"
```

You'll notice the backticks (`) around the word status. This tells MySQL that it should be read as is, and not as a keyword.

Comment: no effect :( I was playing around a bit and can only get the form to display the previously definded variable if I re-query them on the site where want to display them (profile summary page). Now I have new problem where the username and password belong to one account, and all the other data to another. what am I doing wrong in storing the data to the session?